# Open Flickr From Third Party iOS App

Tags: ios, hyperlink, flickr

I want to forward my users to the Flickr app -if they have it of course- and if they don't to Flickr mobile. I want to make sure that they will see my page. I can do this with Facebook and Twitter by a link like twitter://... However, I don't know the link style of Flickr. Can someone help me. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're thinking of is called a URL-Scheme.
I trying to look up the info, but I think that the developers at Flickr didn't think this through. An example post of my search is right [here](http://www.flickr.com/groups/flickrapp/discuss/72157634148954925/).

It seems that Flickr only has the `flickr://` scheme, which opens the app, but not more than that. It's a shame.

Comment: For the ones who seeks a solution, you can use safari for this as I did.

Answer (score 0):

The new version has `flickr://photos/username/photoID`. You can either use the username or nsid. Both work.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the way to solve this is to open the web URL. The website will redirect you to the app if it's installed.

More on this here:
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

Example in Objective-C:

```
                                                           //Photo owner id/photo id
NSString *flickrUrlString = @"https://www.flickr.com/photos/12037949754@N01/155761353";
NSURL *flickrUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: flickrUrlString];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:flickrUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:flickrUrl];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to open url: %@", flickrUrl);
}
```