# iOS: URL Scheme to open specific profile in flickr app

Tags: ios, url, flickr, url-scheme

I checked the plist of the flickr app and it lets me open it with the url handler

```
flickr://
```

but what is the argument to open a specific profile page? I can't find any documentation for that...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look at my answer here:
[Open Flickr From Third Party iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576285/open-flickr-from-third-party-ios-app/18582607#18582607).

Unfortunately, Flickr didn't add this option.

Comment: The lack of usability by most of these url scheme implementations is hilarious... Just kicking the user into the flickr app is of no use to me then...